# How do you run a Postman test multiple times in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, postman

I have been looking into `postman` and `JMeter` for a school project and I know that you can run a `postman` test and get results using `JMeter`. I have also been told that the main reason for `JMeter` is that you can run that test many times in `JMeter` unlike `postman`.

Does anyone know how to do this? got any links or resources you can share or just know the answer yourself?

I have been searching online for answers and I have connected the 2 application through using the `HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` but this only provides me with 1 result and I have been unable to find anything that talks about using this to run the test many times.

If anyone is able to provide me with a solution it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all you need to convert your Postman test into a JMeter test, the approach is as simple as running test in Postman using JMeter as the proxy:

   - Configure JMeter for recording. The fastest way is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature/) 
     feature

     - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create". You should get a Test Plan structure like:

       [image]
     - Expand [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and click "Start"
2. Prepare Postman for recording.

   - From Postman's main menu choose `File -> Settings -> Proxy` and configure it like:

     [image]
3. Run your collection in Postman
4. JMeter should generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)
5. Now expand [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and set the desired number of threads (virtual users) and loops (iterations)
6. Run your test in JMeter
7. Inspect results using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

More information: [Building a Web Test Plan - Adding Users](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users)

Comment: Ok I think I understand thank you. Before I saw your answer I did find a postman to JMeter converter but it says it cannot copy the global variables into the test, which is fair nothing would be that simple. Does doing it this way keep any global variables that would be used in Postman? or will they all have to be hard coded into the test.

Comment: **Note for other people -** Once you have configured a test in the thread group you can then save it and run it in the CMD as you don't really want to run these in the UI :)

Answer (score 0):

After you record the script in JMeter, you can run multiple times in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) element by (increasing Threads Number to run script with multi threads or) increasing Loop Count, if you want to just repeat the script

> thread group element controls the number of threads JMeter will use to execute your test. The controls for a thread group allow you to:
>
> Set the number of threads
>
> Set the ramp-up period
>
> Set the number of times to execute the test